# Problems wit sign me up plugin

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi i am trying to use Sign me up Plugin for my application. But unable to get it running. There are so many issues and errors.

Plugin i have downloaded is:-

```
sign_me_up-2.0
```

But there are so many errors i am getting

```
Ex:- Declaration of SignMeUpComponent::initialize() should be compatible with Component::initialize(Controller $controller)
```

I have tried for tutorials and serached for solutions online. But no luck...

Can anyone help me out on how to use this plugin ???
What i reffered :-

```
http://www.jotlab.com/2011/sign-me-up-a-cakephp-registration-plugin
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your version of CakePHP is compatible with the plugin. I understand between version 1.3 and 2, they took advantage of the newer features of PHP which included strongly-typed method parameters. The error you're receiving is that the `SignMeUpComponent` inherits from the `Component` class which is in framework core. If the component wants to override the `initialize` method, it must follow the same method/function signature.

If the plugin is on Git and you feel comfortable in doing so, clone it and update all the components methods, and then put in a pull request so you're changes can be merged in.

Alternatively use an earlier version of CakePHP.

Comment: Good question, apart from the 'downgrade CakePHP' part. Apparently this plugin hasn't been maintained for 2+ years, which is often a bad sign. It's probably best to keep CakePHP up-to-date and either fix the plugin (as suggested) or look for another plugin that offers the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Fwiw, there's also a 'Users' plugin developed by CakeDC; https://github.com/CakeDC/users although that one hasn't been updated a while, it may be worth looking at.